# Styling overlapping elements

Tags: css

I've got this design I'm having trouble building out.  I've included an image that helps to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.  Basically there's a hero section and another section beneath it.  On the section beneath, one of the elements overlaps part of the hero, so there's sort of a jig-saw effect happening.  The issue is that when I move the images column up, there's a white space beneath.  I've tried a dozen different ways to get this to work but still no luck.

```
<section class="hero" style="--bg-img-url: url(https://cdn.thefabricator.com/a/new-developments-in-modern-pipe-welding-1580141284.webp?size=1000x)">
    <div class="site-container">
        <div class="hero__container">
            <div class="hero__header">
                <h1>Here is my header</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="hero__subheader">
                <h2>here is my subheader</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="hero__button">
                <a href="<?php echo get_field('hero_section_button')['url']; ?>" class="button">button</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="after-hero">
    <div class="after-hero__wrapper">
        <div class="images">
            <img src="https://cdn.thefabricator.com/a/new-developments-in-modern-pipe-welding-1580141296.webp?size=1000x" alt="">
            <img src="https://cdn.thefabricator.com/a/new-developments-in-modern-pipe-welding-1580141290.webp?size=1000x" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h6>Top header here</h6>
            <h2>Header goes here</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.hero {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 82vh;

    .site-container {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 30px;
    }

    &__container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100%;

    }

    &__header {
        max-width: 750px;

        h1 {
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 68px;
            line-height: 1.25;
        }
    }

    &__subheader {
        h2 {
            color: green;
            font-size: 28px;
        }
    }

    &__button {
        margin-top: 75px;
    }

    &::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: var(--bg-img-url);
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        z-index: -10;

    }
}

.after-hero {

    &__wrapper {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;

        .images {
            width: 100%;
            top: -80px;
            position: relative;

            img {
                width: 100%;
                max-height: 300px;
                object-fit: cover;
            }
        }

        .content {
            padding: 50px 90px;
            background-color: green;
            position: relative;
            width: 55%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;

        }
    }
}
```

Link to a codepen:https://codepen.io/paul-molnar/pen/rNPLgor

[image]

Comment: The easiest way to to do this is with Grid layout. Create rows and columns and then place items in any rows and columns you want, even overlapping.

Comment: Change `top: -80px` to `margin-top: 80px` - `top` basically retains the original block position/space within the layout, but shifts the element outside of document flow, where `margin` is within the document flow and will affect elements around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative `margin-top`. I brought your code to the desired result if you don't mind:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hero {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 82vh;
  min-height: 240px;
  display: grid;
}
.hero__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px 30px 120px;
}
.hero__header {
  max-width: 750px;
}
.hero__header h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 68px;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
.hero__subheader h2 {
  color: green;
  font-size: 28px;
}
.hero__button {
  margin-top: 75px;
}

.after-hero {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 55%;
  position: relative;
}
.after-hero .images-wrapp {
  margin-top: -80px; /*  */
  position: relative;
}
.after-hero .images {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}
.after-hero .images img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.after-hero .content {
  padding: 50px 90px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero" style="background: url(https://cdn.thefabricator.com/a/new-developments-in-modern-pipe-welding-1580141284.webp?size=1000x) center / cover">
  <div class="hero__container">
     <div class="hero__header">
        <h1>Here is my header</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="hero__subheader">
        <h2>here is my subheader</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="hero__button">
        <a href="#" class="button">button</a>
     </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="after-hero">
  <div class="images-wrapp">
    <div class="images">
      <img src="https://cdn.thefabricator.com/a/new-developments-in-modern-pipe-welding-1580141296.webp?size=1000x" alt="">
      <img src="https://cdn.thefabricator.com/a/new-developments-in-modern-pipe-welding-1580141290.webp?size=1000x" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h6>Top header here</h6>
    <h2>Header goes here</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```